# R-shiny split data and render data table

Tags: r, shiny

I have a dataframe like below (df1). I am filtering the df1 based on user input and can summarize the data to reflect the total numbers. But based on user input I want to split the data to break it into multiple tables, group and summarize the data in a specific format.I'm not sure if i need to melt the data and then do pivot_wide.

```
df1<-structure(list(record_id = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), Name = c("Anna", 
"Anna", "Anna", "Anna", "Anna", 
"Anna"), Country = c("USA", "USA", 
"USA", "USA", "USA", 
"USA"), 
    record_id.y = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", 
    "6"), emp_id = c("1837100", "203013", 
    "1820027", "1852508", "2123813", 
    "1887667"), rel = c("S", "M", "I", 
    "F", "I", "I"), Date = structure(c(17869, 
    17862, 17865, 17848, 17862, 17848), class = "Date"), date1 = structure(c(1639134523, 
    1638615986, 1638764440, 1638876083, 1644605968, 1638764441
    ), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), date2 = structure(c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, 1638615988, NA), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
    ), tzone = "UTC"), typec = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1
    ), typer = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), typey = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0), is_present = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_
    )), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")

My code
table1 <- reactive({
    req(input$Name, 
        input$Country, 
        input$Status, 
        input$Type)
    my_data %>%
      select(Name,
             Country,
             typec,
             typer,
             typey,
             date1,
             date2,
             Date,
             rel) %>%
      filter(Name %in% input$Name,
             Date >= input$dates[1] &
               Date <= input$dates[2]) %>%
      
      filter(
        (('Status1' %in% input$status) & !is.na(date1)) | 
          (('Status2' %in% input$status) & !is.na(date2)) 
      ) %>%
      filter( 
        (('C' %in% input$type) & typec == '1') | 
          (('R' %in% input$type) & typer == '1') |
          (('Y' %in% input$type) & typey == '1')
      ) %>%
      filter(Rel %in% input$rel) %>%
      
      split(input$Name) %>%
      group_by(get(input$status, 
               input$rel, 
               input$type)) %>%
      summarize(Total=n(), .groups = "drop")
    
  }) 
output$table <- DT::renderDataTable({
    datatable(table1())
  })

Desired output format
Results for Anna
 C R Y
Status1 
Status2 


Results for Vika
 C R Y
Status1
Status2
```

Comment: Can you provide the sample data by posting the output from `dput(df1)`?

Comment: Updated the test data and code

Comment: It looks as if your `%>% split(input$Name) %>% .` is returning a named-list, not sure how `group_by` is working on that data. Perhaps end your `table1 <- reactive(..)` after `split(input$Name)`, and then have multiple `renderDT`s that work on `table1()$Anna` and `table1()$Vika`.

Comment: ... I don't know what you expect `split(..)` to be doing here, I think it's not really the best way to go.

Comment: I intend to split table by name.Create one table each for a name. If user selects 5 names then create 5 tables. Default is all the names.

Comment: Have you figured out how to use `renderUI` to do that? You'll also need to keep track of the number of tables and, when the split changes, delete unused tables.

Comment: Still not sure. Trying a couple of different options. I am open to suggestions.